# Meaning of hessian for vector valued functions

Tags: calculus

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth function. What do the eigenvalues of $H(f)$ tell us? In particular, if $H(F)$ has both positive and negative eigenvalues at a critical point $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, does $F$ have a "saddle point"?

Comment: The "hessian" isn't a matrix but a rank 3 tensor...

Comment: Quite right, my mistake. In any case, what is the meaning of this tensor? How can we use it to discuss the geometry of the graph?

Comment: Rank 3 tensors don't have the concept of eigenvalues. As for geometry of $F$, just analyze its components separately.